# Получение input элемента по тегу name

Tags: java

Есть страница, на которой находится
'input' элемент, с тегом 'hidden', но в его 'value' находится строка которую надо получить, как это реализовать в java?

Comment: Вы хотите получить значение при сабмите формы или запросить страницу и достать значение из элемента?

Comment: Сначала надо достать это значение из страницы, а уже после этого, оно используется

Comment: Что значит достать из страницы? Чем достать? В результате какого действия начинать доставать?

Comment: В результате запроса к ней, получить этот элемент, я думаю так

Comment: Достать у HttpServletRequest request атрибут. String hidden =  (String) request.getAttribute("name_field")